# Is there a Way to get Neo4j APOC connection strings to accept spaces or \ characters?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm working on attempting to pull process data from OSI PI JDBC into my knowledge graph in Neo4j with the APOC library. Having trouble getting the authentication setup:

With the following CYPHER query I get the error Illegal character in path at index 48 (space between Integrated Security)

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:pioledbent://[server]/DataSource=[server];Integrated Security=SSPI;","[AF Database].Asset.Element")
YIELD row
RETURN row.Name;
```

With this CYPHER query I am able get the JDBC driver to prompt for authentication but it always fails saying Invalid Credentials. Username must be non-empty.

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:pioledbent://[server]/DataSource=[Server];DCA=file.dca;ProtocolOrder=https/Soap:5461,NetTcp:5462;","[AF Database].Asset.Element") 
YIELD row
RETURN row.Name;
```

Does anyone know if APOC can accept spaces in the connection string so I can get the Integrated Security=SSPI query working?

Comment: I haven't tried it in practice, but try to substitute the whitespace with %20 sign.

Comment: This worked to represent the space! Still having connection issues but this got me a step further. Thank you!